# Setting UIBarButtonItem appearance resulted in weird behaviour with back button

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

```
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
        ]
```

```
        // set nav bar button item
        // solution 1 - this will not work properly.
        // refer to the Imgur 
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        
        //
```

```
        // solution 2: this works fine
        let app = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
        app.normal.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        
        let navBarApp = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarApp.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarApp.buttonAppearance = app
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarApp
```

I am not sure why **solution 1** doesn't fully work but I think the issue is related to this line `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)`. Is this not the right way to set appearance and styling(font/color/etc) for navBar and BarButtonItem?

Solution 2 works fine so I am not going to attach anything.

Edit: looks like the link expired. Here's the new Link for solution 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZKDS.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue for solution 1, but honestly have no idea why I need both `normal` and `highlighted` state for it to work properly.

Need to add the following

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .highlighted)
```